# Accessing variable in React

Tags: javascript

Hi there guy's i'm completely new to ReactJS. I'm tryng to create a basic post request for a post. To understand syntax... How to parse this response in order to access single value? Tried with values.email but dosen't work.

This is coming from values of a form:

```
JSON.stringify({
          values: values,
      })
```

i need to access single values but values return:

```
Map { "email": "johndoe@mail.com", "password": "12345678", "remember": false }
```

Thank you so much guy's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `values`:

```
Map { "email": "johndoe@mail.com", "password": "12345678", "remember": false }
```

The "Map" at the start of that line indicates that `values` is a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) not a plain [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). To read a property of a map for a given key, you use `values.get("keyName")` instead of `values.keyName`.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object holds key-value pairs. Hopefully my example below provides clarity on accessing the `"email"` property in the `Map` object.

```
// declare variable called 'values' that creates a new Map object instance
var values = new Map();

// set three key-value pairs in the 'values' Map object
values.set("email", "johndoe@mail.com");
values.set("password", "12345678");
values.set("remember", false);
```

Console logging `values` will print the `Map` object originally provided:

```
console.log(values);
// Map { "email": "johndoe@mail.com", "password": "12345678", "remember": false }
```

Lastly, to access the `"email"` property stated in your question, call the [Map.prototype.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) method.

```
values.get("email");
// returns "johndoe@mail.com"
```

If needed, access the two other properties `"password"` and `"remember"` like so:

```
values.get("password");
// returns "12345678"
values.get("remember");
// returns false
```